# Applied for UK Visa in the US: Decision made but not shipped

Tags: usa, uk, tourist-visas, standard-visitor-visas

I was hoping to travel to the UK on Wednesday, September 26, and applied for a general visit visa (since I'm an Indian citizen on a student visa in the US), and paid for the expedited 5-day processing. I went for my biometrics on September 17, and shipped my application that very day, which reached them on Tuesday.

On Friday, September 21 I receive an email that a decision had been made, and my application was going to be dispatched... except it's Monday today and looks like it's still not been shipped (I'm checking the UPS return label I included as part of my application). What's going on? Any way I could reach them? (The helpline guys are clueless)

Edit: My main concern is, I need my passport back for the main non-UK leg of my trip, and there seems to be no way of reaching out to them.

Comment: Here's the contents of Friday's email:
Your UK visa application has been despatched from the UK Visa Section. 

If you submitted your application at a visa application centre you will receive an email within 1-2 working days from TLS or VFS on collecting your decision. Please ensure you check your e-mail account.

       OR

If you submitted your application at the following locations: 
<a bunch of European nations>, 
you will receive an email from DHL within 1-2 working days with your waybill number. You can track your application via the DHL website using this waybill number.

Comment: No, this is not post submission anxiety, more the fact that there seems to be no way of reaching them, and I need my passport back for the main, non-UK part of my trip, UK visa be damned.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus There is a brief statement of what happened, along with clear, explicit questions. I don't see any ranting, and the "classic case of UK visa post-submission anxiety" is "OMG, I made some minor mistake on the form will I get my visa I need to know \*panicpanicpanic\*" not "They said they shipped my passport three days ago and they don't seem to have done that."

Comment: I guess the OP wants to know a way to contact them about their passport. Is that right @WheresMyVisa?

Comment: Yup! Because looks like I won't be getting it in time for my Wednesday flight to the UK, but I'd rather not have that affect the rest of my trip (which I'll be booking an alternate flight for), I want it by Friday at worst so I can still continue with the rest of my trip. In any case, learned my lesson, this was just poorly thought out :/

Comment: My UPS tracking page just updated, they shipped it!

Comment: @WheresMyVisa when did they ship it?  My first thought was that you probably got the e-mail when they processed the visa, but that they might not get it to the shipping company until the next business day, especially if they finished processing it after the shipper's pickup time.  Perhaps you should post an answer yourself.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments. Putting on hold.